# xsd - circular dependencies between complex types

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd2code

I am looking at some of the xsd files available here: https://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd/

I see this in https://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd/citation.xsd

```
<xs:complexType name="CI_Citation_Type">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="gco:AbstractObject_Type">
            <xs:sequence>
                ...
                <xs:element name="identifier" type="gmd:MD_Identifier_PropertyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                ...
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="CI_Citation" type="gmd:CI_Citation_Type"/>

<xs:complexType name="CI_Citation_PropertyType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element ref="gmd:CI_Citation"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    ...
</xs:complexType>
```

Which means

- `CI_Citation_PropertyType` contains seq terms of type `CI_Citation_Type`
- and `CI_Citation_Type` contains seq terms of type `MD_Identifier_PropertyType`

On the other hand, I see this in https://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd/referenceSystem.xsd

```
<xs:complexType name="MD_Identifier_Type">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="gco:AbstractObject_Type">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="authority" type="gmd:CI_Citation_PropertyType" minOccurs="0"/>
                ...
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="MD_Identifier" type="gmd:MD_Identifier_Type"/>

<xs:complexType name="MD_Identifier_PropertyType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element ref="gmd:MD_Identifier"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="gco:ObjectReference"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="gco:nilReason"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Which means

- `MD_Identifier_PropertyType` contains seq terms of type `MD_Identifier_Type`
- and `MD_Identifier_Type` contains seq terms of type `CI_Citation_PropertyType`

So

This looks like a circular dependency between xsd types `CI_Citation_PropertyType` and `MD_Identifier_PropertyType`.

My questions:

1. Is this valid/legal xsd? Are such "circular dependencies" a concern in xsd/xml? (I think circular references are accepted in xsd schemas)
2. I try to generate mapping classes for these types. I can't figure it out to deal with such dependencies (in c++, where #includes are sequential. Maybe via forward declarations and pointers...).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD obviously has to allow recursive structures for document models, e.g. where tables are nested within tables. So it should be no surprise that such structures are legal.

I can't help you on how to generate mapping classes, but languages like C++ also allow recursive data structures.

Comment: Hi, I expected recursivity, yes, but I have to admit I was a bit surprised by the xsd circular references. However, that too is not a problem for xsd itself, could be a problem for generated code. Thanks!!